Parallelism with async method: Why do I need to do Task.Run() here and can I avoid it?
I am aiming to improve my understanding regarding Concurrency in C# and ran into a question with a small toy problem I have.
Let's consider an async method async Task<int> CountAsync(int id) that counts something based on a given ID, but for doing so, it has to make a web request for example, thus being async.
Now I would like to parallelize counting multiple different IDs. I asumed that that not awaiting each CountAsync call in a loop should do the job.
var countTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
for (int i = 1; i <= upUntil; i++)
{
    countTasks.Add(CountAsync(i));
}
await Task.WhenAll(countTasks);
var count = countTasks.Select(x => x.Result).Sum();

However, it shows that this is as fast, as simply calling and awaiting each Count inside the loop.
To get the counting to be actually done in parallel, I have to make use of Task.Run() and write my code like this:
var countTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
for (int i = 1; i <= upUntil; i++)
{
    countTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await CountAsync(i)));
}
await Task.WhenAll(countTasks);
var count = countTasks.Select(x => x.Result).Sum();

Or use the alternative with AsParallel() to get some more control over the degree of parallelism.
count = Enumerable.Range(1, upUntil)
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(16)
    .Select(CountAsync)
    .Sum(t => t.Result);

Reading "Concurrency in C#" by Stephen Cleary made me aware of parallelism and asynchronous methods being different and the fact that I am actually in a parallel processing scenario here. However, I would have assumed that not awaiting CountAsync in my first loop and simply collecting the Promises of the async method, would also lead to a speedup in executing, as it can be offloaded to a different thread.
I obviously lack understanding here and would like to figure out what happens behind the scenes in my first example. Also: are my other code examples the way to go when having a parallel operation with async methods? I do not like the use of .Result.
Edit:
As requested I add the CountAsync that I use for my playground example. It counts the number of "A"s in a random "AB" string. Task.Delay is used to make it slow and async, much like the fiddle @Auditive posted. I am curious about the fiddle, because it seems to match what I originally thought would happen. One detail that might be important:
I have implemented the calling code inside a GET Controller Method of a .NET 8 ASP.NET Core application.
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetObjectsSlowlyAsync(int id)
{
    var random = new Random(id);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        if (random.Next(0, 10) == 1)
            yield return "A";
        else
            yield return "B";

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(random.Next(400, 800)));
    }
}

public static async Task<int> CountAsync(int id)
{
    var count = 0;
    await foreach (var x in GetObjectsSlowlyAsync(id))
    {
        if (x == "A") count++;
    }
    return count;
}

The difference I experience with both ways of calling CountAsync is almost ten-fold:



I think using or avoiding Task.Run depends on what type of task CountAsync actually is (CPU- or I/O-bound) and project type (library or UI or web application). Task.Run supposed to execute in another thread grabbed from ThreadPool (and threads may be required to handle web requests), may be scheduled (not executed immediately), oftenly used just to wrap a synchronious operation or "release" UI to proceed operation.

Your first code example (without Task.Run and Parallel) provides "hot" tasks. They started immediately when you adding them to the List, then you just synchronizing their completion with Task.WhenAll. So since they are added without being awaited, they already run in parallel manner. "However, it shows that this is as fast, as simply calling and awaiting each Count inside the loop" - this fiddle disagree with you. There are 1000 dummy tasks, each delayed with 5 sec, and timer shows that all of them completed in 5 sec, which shows "parallel" execution.

While using Task.Run in your code is considered a pure parallel execution (N managed threads are running less or more concurrently). But here you explicitly asks for a separate threadpool thread to execute some workload. In the first case (assuming code is run under TaskScheduler.Default) CountAsync() is executed some of its part by the calling thread, because it makes sense not to grab workhorse from threadpool immediately. Because async/await is about using CPU resources effectively - always while it makes sense. No need to immediately grabbing work horse via CountAsync().

So, in the first case managed threads are used more wisely, i would say, but it is still concurrent execution. In the second case, Task.Run - explicit tool to grab different thread, more concurrent execution (clean fork-join pattern), but less wise using threads. They are threadpool threads, anyway - this is acceptable (depends on workload though).

Just summary of the idea of async/await - threads are used always while it makes sense. Try to review your code once more bearing that in mind. And why calling thread goes back at making a web request (we don't see code of CountAsync() though).

What does CountAsync actually do? If there is code there that blocks or otherwise takes up CPU time then you can't start them on the same thread and parallelize them at the same time, you'd need to offload it from the start.

.Select(CountAsync).Sum(t => t.Result); appears highly suspicious. Why not await the results of the parallel select via WhenAll and Sum the result?

Thanks a lot for all the input. I updated the question to post my CountAsync and also noticed that me doing this inside a ASP.NET Core API Controller method might be important. Since I now assume the context and Threadpool for handling web requests is a factor here.

await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(random.Next(400, 800)));

It seems that you have high expectations about the ability of .NET timers to be triggered in sub-millisecond timespans. In reality any timespan smaller than one millisecond is evaporated to zero:
Task task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(999));
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(task, Task.CompletedTask)); // True

Online demo.
The await in your code awaits a completed Task, so it's equivalent to this:
await Task.CompletedTask;

The result is that your GetObjectsSlowlyAsync is completely synchronous. It is neither slow nor async.
Which makes obvious why you need the Task.Run to parallelize this code. Synchronous code is not parallelized by itself.

As a side note, this PLINQ query is not doing what you expect it to do.
count = Enumerable.Range(1, upUntil)
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(16)
    .Select(CountAsync)
    .Sum(t => t.Result);

The PLINQ library is not async-friendly. In case the CountAsync was actually asynchronous, the Select operator would project all the inputs into incomplete tasks very fast. The WithDegreeOfParallelism policy would affect only the creation of the tasks, not the maximum number of tasks that are concurrently in-flight. Then the .Sum(t => t.Result) would block a bunch of ThreadPool threads, plus the current thread, waiting for the completion of these tasks, for no good reason. The Task.WaitAll method could do the same, blocking only the current thread.

oh wow, I did not expect  that at all. I came up with these times after playing around with printing all A's and B's as the HTTP webpage output and I found that within that timespan it felt to be just the right amount of delay, whereas longer waits in the milliseconds, resulted in me waiting forever for so many characters. Turns out it was just about cross the barrier before these effectively become 0. That explains my issue I assume.
Thanks a lot.

@Roper yeah, you started the question talking about web requests, and then you ended up showing code with sub-millisecond delays. There is no web server that can respond that fast, unless we are talking about requests to the localhost 127.0.0.1. You really have to be cautious when you are simulating things. The simulation should be as close as possible to the real thing.

I went down to the microseconds early in setting up this example and never reconsidered it again. Great catch. Also: Is there away to make the PLINQ statement async-aware and actually parallelize the execution instead of only the task creation?

@Roper no, the PLINQ (AsParallel) will never become async-aware. You would need a brand new library, with all operators new, to support asynchronous parallelism in LINQ style. See this issue for details. Microsoft won't do it.
